# How do I authenticate a preauthenticated LDAP user using spring security using ping access and username passed in the header?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, federated, pingaccess

I was previously using basic auth but I need to switch to federated auth using Ping Access. The user is already authenticated and the username along with the token are sent in the request header. How do I link the username to an ldap user principal using spring security?

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail? For example, is the token you receive from Ping Access a SAML token? If not, what kind of token is it and how would it get verified? It it's a saml token, take a look at `spring-security-saml`. As for looking up via LDAP, you should be able to query a user details service just by the principal value (e.g. the subject). Perhaps with more detail I can be more helpful.

Comment: @jzheaux, it's a jwt token. I'm able to validate this token with Ping Access. The username is in the 'sub' field of the header. I have extended the OncePerRequestFilter class. In the doFilterInternal method I want to map the username to the ldap principal so i can create a new Authentication object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a number of things to consider as you are considering your implementation. Here is a very basic rundown of the pieces in play.

## Filter Chain

The filter chain is typically for differentiating between servlets and the rest of the app. If you have extended `OncePerRequestFilter` then you are likely already on the right path.

If you intend to follow the typical Spring Security model, this filter would prepare an `Authentication` object that can then be authenticated in an `AuthenticationManager`. You might try and use an existing `Authentication` implementation like `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`, or you might create your own and call it `JwtAuthenticationToken`.

## Authentication Manager

`AuthenticationManager` is essentially a collection of providers that can authenticate a token, like your Jwt token. Their contract is separate from servlets and are therefore a bit more flexible.

You would probably create a `JwtAuthenticationProvider` that would validate the token and then invoke a `UserDetailsService` to get the underlying user.

Spring Security doesn't have dedicated support for JWTs, but they do have some libraries that use Nimbus. You could check out the code in spring-security-oauth2-resource-server to see how they are verifying JWTs using a JWK Set Uri. You wouldn't want to depend on that library since it is focused on OAuth, but it might give you some ideas.

## User Details Service

A `UserDetailsService` implementation is responsible for querying a backend and retrieving from it a user. For example, there is `LdapUserDetailsService` that you could possibly use.

## Summary

So, with all of that said, here is a summary of what I would probably do:

1. Create a `JwtAuthenticationToken` object that can house the jwt token and possibly represent a successful authentication when Spring Security completes the verification process.
2. Create a `JwtAuthenticationFilter` that reads the token from the request and populates `JwtAuthenticationToken`, sending it to an `AuthenticationManager`.
3. Create a `JwtAuthenticationProvider` that reads a `JwtAuthenticationToken` and sends it to Nimbus (or Auth0 or some other jwt library) for validation. You will need to decide how you trust that token--Nimbus is capable of checking remotely via a JWK Set Uri or locally via a pre-configured set of public or symmetric keys. (Lots to think about here, too!)
4. Use the `LdapUserDetailsService`, passing it the  name of the parsed subject. The `UserDetails` that comes back can be supplied as the principal for the  `Authentication` object that your provider returns.

## Alternatives

So, let's say that you don't want/need to follow the Spring Security development model, but just want to get something working asap.

The two things that you ultimately need to accomplish are

1. Decide whether or not the token is valid. Spring Security has no OAuth2-free support for this yet, so you will need to roll your own using Nimbus or the like.
2. Configure and invoke `LdapUserDetailsService`. From the `UserDetails` this gives you, you can build an `Authentication` object that you can set on the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Such would be not as flexible over time, but it might get you started a bit faster.

## Other things to think about

You didn't ask about this, but I wonder what you are planning on doing if the token is somehow invalid. For those cases, you may want to look at `AuthenticationEntryPoint`s and `AccessDeniedHandler`s.